# How to convert int to double when using arrow to read in multiple CSVs with open_dataset in R?

Tags: r, csv, apache-arrow

I'm trying to convert a large folder of CSVs to parquet. The dataset it too large to fit into memory, so I'm using arrow.

For some columns, some files have only whole numbers, and others have decimal/float/double. I want it to convert int64 to double when this happens. But instead it throws an error about int and double being "incompatible". Even when I specify `unify_schemas = TRUE`, I still get the error.

I believe arrow is just looking at the first `N` rows of each file to guess the file types. My real dataset has a column with whole numbers for the first 500,000 rows, then a float appears. So arrow only sees integers. Is there an option to force arrow to read *all* the rows before inferring types?

For now I'm using R. But I would accept a Python solution.

### Steps to reproduce

`data/01.csv`

```
a,b
1,1
2,2
```

`data/02.csv`

```
a,b
11,1.1
22,2.2
```

`main.R`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)

csvs <- open_dataset(
  sources = "data/", 
  format = "csv",
  unify_schemas = TRUE,
)

csvs |> glimpse()
```

### Expected Behavior

The two files are read into one dataframe successfully. Column `b` is treated as double. The values of column `b` from file `01.csv` are implicitly converted to `double`

### Actual behaviour

> Error in `open_dataset()`:
> ! Invalid: Unable to merge: Field b has incompatible types: double vs int64

## What I've tried

I tried writing a python script to merge the CSV files into one, and then read in only one file. (`open_dataset` doesn't yet handle one file, only a folder of one file.) I still get an error.

I have hundreds of datasets to do this to. So I'd prefer a solution where I do not have to explicitly enumerate all the columns that should be cast like this. In particular, the `schema` argument to `open_dataset()` expects all columns or no columns. I can't just pass one, it seems. (Or is there a way to do that?)

My next step is to write a script to read the whole dataset as text, and search each cell value for a decimal. Then re-read the whole dataset, and append `.0` to some values. Then I can (hopefully) read it in with `open_dataset()`. I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

While `schema` only takes a full schema or no schema there is `col_types` that allows for partial schemas:

```r
csvs <- open_dataset(
  sources = "data/", 
  format = "csv",
  unify_schemas = TRUE,
  col_types = schema(b = double()))
)
```

Looking through the documentation I have to say that it is not obvious that this exists when looking at `open_dataset` as it is only documented in the more specialized wrapper functions (and even there the for partial schemas is not clear): https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/open_delim_dataset.html

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/38903) to improve the docs.

---

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think the only way out is to specify `schema=`, and since it always infers that the data does not have a header row when that is specified, we must specify all columns.

We *can* try to dynamically create the `schema=` object, however.

```r
types <- list.files("~/StackOverflow/5443120/77557377/data", full.names = TRUE) |>
  lapply(open_dataset, format = "csv") |>
  lapply(function(z) strsplit(z$schema$ToString(), "\n")[[1]])
types <- lapply(1:max(lengths(types)), function(i) sapply(types, `[[`, i))
names(types) <- sapply(types, function(z) sub(":.*", "", z[1]))
types <- lapply(types, function(z) unique(sub(".*: ", "", z)))
types
# $a
# [1] "int64"
# $b
# [1] "int64"  "double"
  
some_types <- c(
  # bits?
  "null", "bool",
  # ints
  "int8", "uint8", "int16", "uint16", "int32", "uint32", "int64", "uint64",
  # floats
  "float16", "float32", "double", "float64",
  # dates/times
  "date32", "date64", "time32", "time64",
  # strings
  "utf8")

types <- lapply(types, function(z) {
  typ <- some_types[max(match(z, some_types))]
  if (typ == "double") typ <- "float64"
  getFunction(typ, where = asNamespace("arrow"))()
})

types
# $a
# Int64
# int64
# $b
# Float64
# double
```

Which we can use directly:

```r
csvs <- open_dataset(
  sources = "~/StackOverflow/5443120/77557377/data", 
  format = "csv",
  unify_schemas = TRUE,
  schema = do.call(schema, types),
  skip = 1
)
collect(csvs)
# # A tibble: 4 × 2
#       a     b
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1   1  
# 2     2   2  
# 3    11   1.1
# 4    22   2.2
```

Note that I had to add `skip=1` since by providing `schemas=`, the arrow package assumes that there are no header rows.

There are certainly more classes than what I provided in `some_types`, and I have not tested exhaustively whether my hierarchy will actually work with all of the different types. If you want to play it safe, then perhaps just adjust the "length > 1" fields manually.